# How to escape URL from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript code and I want make a URL from that JavaScript to alert JavaScript, but the problem is, the URL is not from a variable.

This is my code.

```
function OpenThis(e, t) {
    //this only function
}
OpenThis("//myurl.com/?ref=" + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer), {
    name: "url",
})
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
alert(OpenThis);
```

Comment: You are alerting a function. What do you want to happen?

Comment: You have to pass arguments when you call a function.

Comment: if i can get that text i will use that for something may be redirect

Answer (score 0):

You declared a function, parsed it two variables that are doing nothing, you have to make sure the variables do something inside the function, and perhaps return a value. All your code is doing now is alerting a function